# Regression in function call not returning same output as regression outside function

Tags: r

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
get_contribution_table <- function(question_id){
  fit <- lm(answer_correct ~ num_players,
          data = filter(contribution_df, question_id == question_id))
  print(summary(fit))
}
```

I run `get_contribution_table(27)`

And get this output:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    0.70648    0.00514  137.49 <0.0000000000000002 ***
num_players   -0.00154    0.00436   -0.35                0.72
```

However, when I just manually define the filter like so:

```
lm(answer_correct ~ num_players,data = filter(contribution_df, question_id == 27)
```

I get different estimates:

```
               Estimate Std. Error t value                                                 Pr(>|t|) CI Lower  CI Upper  DF
(Intercept)    0.73548   0.041228 17.8395 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050041  0.65437  0.816587 323
num_players   -0.12723   0.035730 -3.5608 0.000425282833018741739366380683051716005138587206602097 -0.19752 -0.056934 323
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on default `mtcars` dataset. Can you provide a example to reproduce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you dun

```
filter(contribution_df, question_id == question_id)
```

It's just checking that the `question_id` column is equal to itself. `dplyr` doesn't know which value is a column and which is your local variable name. To get around this, you can explictly use the `.env` or `.data` pronouns. You can use

```
filter(contribution_df, question_id == .env$question_id)
```

To make it clear you want to use your local function variable.

Comment: Ah! Such a silly mistake. Thanks so much!